# GitLab Pipelines: zip: command not found after installing zip on docker image?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to zip my dist folder and post to it Azure's kudu zipdeploy endpoint but I keep getting this error regardless of the fact that I have installed a zipping package myself.

My docker image: [weltn24/up-docker-node-chrome-headless](https://hub.docker.com/r/weltn24/up-docker-node-chrome-headless/tags/) 
on tag: `chrome-66_node-10.0_yarn-1.6.0`

The part that fails in my yml file:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install p7zip p7zip-full
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
    - cd dist/AngularTemplate; zip -r ../dist.zip *; cd ..; cd..
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist.zip
```

The commands on the 4'th line is failing with zip: command not found.

Comment: Just speculating here, might need a `-y` for the `apt-get` bit? ie `apt-get -y install p7zip p7zip-full`, also might be worth putting the full path to where `zip` is installed?

Comment: @Rekovni thanks -- I have eventually found out there were 2 mistakes in my code: 1. Installing package named p7zip and then trying to use package zip, instead I have installed zip unzip: `apt-get install zip unzip` -- thats it, that solved the zip problem and then the path to my artifact was wrong as it's inside a folder not in the root, so I change the zip line to: `zip -r ../../dist.zip *` instead and all is good in the world!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Correct script below:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get install zip unzip
    - yarn install
    - ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod
    - cd dist/AngularTemplate; zip -r ../../dist.zip *; cd ..; cd..
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist.zip
```

Was installing the wrong Zip package and then puttin my archive in the wrong folder.

Comment: if not working then use this 
- apt-get update
- apt-get install -y zip